# PHP Object to JSON choosing properties

Tags: php, json, object

I want to convert an object to JSON with the possibility of choosing which properties to convert.

```
<?php

class MyObject
{

    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $sub1;
    protected $sub2;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->sub1 = new MySubObject;
        $this->sub2 = new MySubObject;
    }

    public function json(array $array)
    {
        $arrayJson = array();
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $arrayJson[$value] = $this->////////// HERE /////// ;
        }
        return json_encode($arrayJson);
    }

    public function debug()
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}
```

Then call something like this:

```
$MyObject= new MyObject(1, 'waffles');
$MyObject->debug();
echo $MyObject->json(array('id','name','sub1->x','sub2->z'));
```

Debug output:

```
object(Produto)#3 (3) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name":protected]=>
  string(6) "waffles"
  ["sub1":protected]=>
  object(MySubObject)#3 (3) {
    ["x"]=>
    1
    ["y"]=>
    2
    ["z"]=>
    3
  }
  ["sub2":protected]=>
  object(MySubObject)#3 (3) {
    ["x"]=>
    1
    ["y"]=>
    2
    ["z"]=>
    3
  }
}
```

I wanted the output of JSON to look like this:

```
{ "id": 1,  "name": "waffles", "sub1": {"x": 1}, "sub2": {"z": 3} }
```

I'm having trouble working out the 'json' function, maybe this is not the best approach. Or you can tell if there is another way to convert an object to JSON by choosing which fields to convert.

I forgot to say that objects can have sub objects within sub objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rasclatt's answer helped me to set up this function.

```
public function json(array $array)
{
    $arrayJson = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, '->') !== false) {
            $subobjexp = explode('->', $value);
            $arr = array();
            $ref = &$arr;
            while ($key = array_shift($subobjexp)) {
                $ref = &$ref[$key];
            }
            $subobjexp = explode('->', $value);
            eval("\$ref = \$this->$value;");
            $arrayJson[$subobjexp[0]] = $arr[$subobjexp[0]];
        } else {
            eval("\$arrayJson[\$value] = \$this->$value;");
        }

    }
    return json_encode($arrayJson);
}
```

Surely it still needs some polishing, I have not used enough to show errors. If anyone wants to indicate an error or improvement, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to do something like this. Note, this should get you started, you can finish it to get the exact output you want:

```
public function json(array $array)
{
    $arrayJson = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        # See if there is a relation
        if(strpos($value,'->') !== false) {
            # Explode and remove any empty fields
            $subobjexp = array_filter(explode('->',$value));
            # See if there is an internal param with this value
            if(isset($this->{$subobjexp[0]})) {
                # Assign a shorthand variable
                $arg    =   $this->{$subobjexp[0]};
                # If there is a second arg, try and extract
                if(isset($subobjexp[1]))
                    $arrayJson[$subobjexp[0]][$subobjexp[1]] = (!empty($arg->{$subobjexp[1]}))? $arg->{$subobjexp[1]} : false;
            }
        }
        else
            $arrayJson[$key] = $value;
    }
    return json_encode($arrayJson);
}
```

Note that parameters like `x` and `z` need to be public variables inside the `MySubObject` class or else you can't access them without a get-type method in those other sub classes.